# how to get the content of another php file without execution?

Tags: php

I want to get the content of another file without execution even the PHP open and closing part too.

Thanks in Advance :-)

**content.php file content**

```
<?php

    $a = hello;
    $b = vishal;
    $b = $a.' '.$b;

?>
```

**Render/index File**

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('content.php');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

Comment: can u explain more

Comment: @S.Sachith I want to print the content of A file using B File. i mean I have some code in the content.php file and want to print that code as it is without execution.

expected output will be : 

<?php

    $a = hello;
    $b = vishal;
    $b = $a.' '.$b;

?>

Comment: And what problem occurs currently when you run the code you've shown?

Comment: @ADyson I am not getting any output. after running index.php it's getting blank. there is no warning, not an error in logs.

Comment: Strange. Have you tested it with just a simple .txt file?

Comment: @ADyson yes .txt extension files are working but I want to get the content of .php files

Comment: ok I'm thinking actually if you're viewing this output in a browser, it might be interpreting the `<` as the start of a HTML tag, so everything then seems to be within a tag (and thus wouldn't be rendered directly by the browser). try a) checking the raw output using your browser's View Source feature, and b) encoding the output with htmlspecialchars() before you echo it.

Comment: You can also get the data using jQuery ajax and php won't show any output without execution so may be you need to change the approach here.

Comment: @ADyson why are telling it's not working. i didn't get that it works for me

Comment: @VishalVishwakarma Have you tried my suggestion from [my earlier comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69043166/how-to-get-the-content-of-another-php-file-without-execution/69043452#comment122024288_69043166) yet? That is almost certainly the issue, but you need to verify it (especially as we don't even know if you're using PHP CLI, or with a browser)

Comment: @Don'tPanic this will help me out thanks.
ADyson thanks for your effort ajax is a good option but this code is, for example, I have to do something else there in my project.

Comment: I did not suggest AJAX, you're confusing me with another commenter. My suggestion was basically the same as Don't Panic's